# Argument of `#selector` does not refer to an initializer or method

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm trying to perform a protocol extension method in the background:

```
performSelectorInBackground(#selector(retrieveCategories()), withObject: nil)
```

However I get the below error message:

```
Argument of `#selector` does not refer to an initializer or method
```

Here is my protocol declaration:

```
@objc protocol DataRetrievalOperations {
    optional func retrieveCategories()
    ...
}
```

And my extension:

```
extension DataRetrievalOperations {
    func retrieveCategories() {
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: try removing removing the `()` after `#selector(retrieveCategories`

Comment: @luk2302 now it complains: `Argument of selector refers to a method that is not exposed to Objective-C`. Proposed Xcode Fix: `Add @objc to expose this method to Objective-C`. Although using that fix adds `@objc` keyword into my protocol conformation near my class name which messes it up.

Comment: What version of swift are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add an `@Objc` method in a Protocol Extension. You need to extend the Class which inherits NSObject and that Protocol and add the `objc` function there like so:

```
@objc protocol DataRetrievalOperations {
    optional func retrieveCategories()
}

class aClass: NSObject, DataRetrievalOperations {
    func method() {
        performSelectorInBackground(#selector(retrieveCategories), withObject: nil)
    }
}

extension aClass {
    @objc func retrieveCategories(){

    }
}
```

This will work.

Comment: Yeah it's working now. Thanks. Much appreciated. Lots of `@objc` but that's the unfortunate deal with Swift at the moment. Also I removed `@objc` from the extension and it still worked.Why is that. BTW if I somehow achieve non-optionality for the method, will I still require `@objc` keywords with the same structure you proposed?

Comment: That's because your class is inheriting `NSObject` . So you don't have to mark the method as `@Objc`. You either write the `@Objc` for your class or you inherit `NSObject`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#selector(DataRetrievalOperations.retrieveCategories)
```

With omitting class (or protocol) name in `#selector(...)` notation, Swift assumes the enclosing class, which may be a ViewController, I guess.

---

One more issue:
It seems Swift cannot implement @objc protocol methods with default implementation in protocol extension.
(I think I have heard something about this, but I couldn't find any articles for now.)

You may need to implement it in your own class's extension or find another way.

```
extension CategoriesViewController {
    func retrieveCategories() {
        //...
    }
}
```

---

I need to add that this will solve the first issue and `#selector(retrieveCategories)` will work.

Comment: This causes the following crash: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:]: target does not implement selector (*** -[En_Yakın.CategoriesViewController retrieveCategories])'`

Comment: To what object are you sending `performSelectorInBackground` method? You need to write something like this `anObject.performSelectorInBackground(...)` where `anObject` is implementing the selector.

Comment: My ViewController class conforms to the data retrieval operations protocol. The `performSelectorInBackground` happens inside the ViewController and requests the data. Should I create a separate object? Calling it on my ViewController class also failed.

Comment: The error message is indicating that your `CategoriesViewController` does NOT implementing `retrieveCategories` method. Show how you declared that method.

Comment: It's implemented in a separate file. I used `@objc` keyword for the protocol declaration. Therefore the method is an optional.

Comment: I see. You have another issue in implementing `optional` method. I'll be add some code when ready.

Comment: I believe what you're talking about is answered by @Dershowitz123 ?

Comment: @CanSürmeli , yes, main part of my answer is a duplicate of Dershowitz123's.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you too man. Much appreciated. You really helped me debug the problem to the core. Take care.